# Export large data to xls format: System out of memory Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, export-to-excel

I am exporting a large DataTable to an Excel sheet (.xls) format. I call stored procedure here, which returns the DataTable. The stored procedure used to return 7,50,000 rows with 93 columns.

In back end, if I pass the parameters for the stored procedure, it takes 8 mins to complete the process, since it is a long process.

But when I call the procedure from the front end, while assigning the records to the DataTable, "System Out Of Memory" exception occurring.

So When I google it, I came to know it is because the size exceeds the server RAM size, so it throws this exception.
When I export small DataTable it works fine.

What is the alternate way for this? Anyone suggest me. Below is my code,

C#:

```
            DataTable dt = BindDatatable();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "MBQ_Auto.xls"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            //Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            //Response.ContentType = "text/tab-separated-values";
            string str = string.Empty;
            foreach (DataColumn dtcol in dt.Columns)
            {
                Response.Write(str + dtcol.ColumnName);
                str = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");
            int rowCount = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                str = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    Response.Write(str + Convert.ToString(dr[j]));
                    str = "\t";
                }
                Response.Write("\n");
                if (unchecked(++rowCount % 1024 == 0))
                    Response.Flush();
            }
            Response.End();
```

Comment: If it is too big for server memory what's it going to do to the client? (And what happens if one of the fields contains a tab character?)

Comment: The xls file format does not support more than just over 65,000 rows. To have more rows you need to use xlsx.

Comment: I am exporting more than 2 lakhs records using xls.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use DataTable for this kind of problem.
DataTable stores the entire data in memory.

You should use the **[DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx)** to fetch rows from database.